# Trying to setup old Wireless Modem as Repeater - Huwaei HG630a as Client

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, wireless-bridge, repeater

I have a old wireless modem which i would like to configure as a repeater (Model: Huawei - Home gateway HG630a). Even after configuring the parameters based on my research, its not working. My Main Router is Huawei HG8145V5 which connects to Fibre broadband also enabled wifi on it.

Could you please help me configure the Wireless repeater settings correctly

Server AP Settings:
[image: Server Config]
Client Config Pages:
[image: Client Settings]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looking  below (slightly different model), it is does not work as a repeater.  You would need to hook it up to your network by Ethernet and then use the Wireless capability that way   https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/how-to-convert-the-echolife-hg8245h-router-to-a-wifi-extender/thread/527237-100181

Comment: Would you like me to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking below (slightly different model), it is does not work as a repeater. You would need to hook it up to your network by Ethernet and then use the Wireless capability that way forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/… – John Jun 20 at 16:36
Thanks John